# Auto line break in a specified window

Tags: auto-fill-mode

I copy content to `*.org` file, but it does not break lines (fill) automatically.

[image]

It's a very long sentence.

[image]

How could I enable it to fill automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`auto-fill-mode` is what you look for.

You can type `M-x auto-fill-mode` to toggle it to be enabled,
then type `SPC` to let it do filling automatically after copying/yanking the content.